# Why does Transformer return &lt and &gt instead of < and >?

Tags: java, xml, transformer-model

```
trnsformer.transform(DomSource, streamResult);
```

Input in DomSource contains many `<br>` tags, but instead I get `&gt` and `&lt` instead of `<` and `>`  `<br>` return as `&lt br &gt`

I know `&lt &gt` are equivalent to `<>`. How can I make transformer class to change the encoding and return `<br>` instead ?

**XML creator**

```
public class CreatXML 
{ 

  public static void main(String[] args){

  try {
    File article = new File("article.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (article);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    while (scan.hasNext())
    { 
      str.append(scan.nextLine());
      str.append("<br>");
    }
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();

    Element body  = doc.createElement("div");
    doc.appendChild(body);

    Attr classAttr = doc.createAttribute("class");
    classAttr.setValue("code");
    body.setAttributeNode(classAttr);

    Element p = doc.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(str.toString()));
    body.appendChild(p);

    TransformerFactory transFatory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transFatory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(doc);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    transformer.transform(dom, result);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());

  }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
  }
}
```

**input sample**

`<br>`this is an input sample`<br>`

**output**

`<?xml [stuff] ><div><p>&lt;br&gt;`this is an input sample`&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</p></div>`

Comment: I have not seen that behavior when using a Transformer.  Please edit your question and provide a [short but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem, along with example input and XSLT so others can observe your issue.

Comment: @VGR thanx for reply. question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(str.toString()));
```

You don't have any `<br>` elements in your Document.  You have a single `<p>` element whose textual content contains occurrences of the four characters `<`, `b`, `r`, and `>`.  In accordance with well-formed XML, those characters are being encoded in the manner you're seeing.

In other words, `createTextNode` does not create XML elements.

Instead of a StringBuilder, you'll need to create separate text nodes and element nodes:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(scan.nextLine()));
    p.appendChild(doc.createElement("br"));
}
```